# VM Pulling IP out of my DHCP Range

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dhcp

I've set up a 2016 server on my laptop to mess around with, and added the usual suspects (AD, DNS, DHCP).

I set the DHCP pool to `192.168.0.20 - 192.168.0.250`.

All my physical machines are withing that scope so far.

However, my VM is set to `10.0.2.15`.

My **server** ipconfig:

[image]

My **VM** ipconfig:

[image]

I'm using Virtualbox... any ideas?

Comment: You are using a virtualized network (a private network only accessible to your PC and your VMs). Use a bridged or NAT connection to get your server into your local network.

Comment: Set your VM to use a BRIDGED network connection. When using NAT networking the IP is automatically assigned in the 10. range, and is on a differant network than the physiical LAN. changing to bridged mode will cause the VM to pull from the DHCP server and participate in the LAN directly.

Comment: @GiantTree Haha, that fixed it!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a virtualized network, a private network only accessible to your PC and your VMs.

In order to get your server into your local network, use a bridged connection or a NAT connection.